# why child class enhanced by spring cglib could not extend the parent protected property?

Tags: spring, cglib

There is an abstract class with a protected property,

```
public abstract class Base {
    protected long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

and there are two class extends `Base`

```
@Component
public class A extends Base {
}

@Repository
public class B extends Base{
}
```

the only diff is that they are using diff annotation.

Now there is a test

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class BaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private A a;
    @Autowired
    private B b;
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(a.time); // 1563372891999
        System.out.println(b.time); // 0

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName()); // A
        System.out.println(b.getClass().getSimpleName()); // B$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b08d2d91

    }
}
```

why `B` enhanced by spring cglib cannot extend the time property?

Answer (score 0):

As the `Repository` annotation provides extra functionality, https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-exception-translation

> The postprocessor automatically looks for all exception translators (implementations of the PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface) and advises all beans marked with the @Repository annotation so that the discovered translators can intercept and apply the appropriate translation on the thrown exceptions.